# How to customise azurerm_container_service with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I am trying to use terraform to set up DC/OS on Azure, following this guide: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/container_service.html

But it does not seem to let you modify Load Balancer and Network Security Group, e.g. I'd like to be able to customise **Inbound NAT Rules** and **Inbound Security Rules**.

Does anyone know how I can do this please?

Comment: @Daiel Lin Based on my knowledge, it is not possible. If possible, you could open ports on Azure Portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my knowledge, it is not possible.

I check the link you provided, it does not allow you modify load balancer parameters. If you want to open more ports, you could do it on Azure Portal, please refer to this link:[Enable public access to an Azure Container Service application](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-enable-public-access).

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Thank you so much for answering my question Walter.